# SWIFT unordered function parameters

Tags: swift

(SWIFT SPECIFICALLY)
lets say i have a function like this

```
static func * (complex: i, number: Int) -> i{
    return i(number*complex.times)
}
```

as you can see, i want to be able to multiply a complex number by an integer.
however, this only works if the complexe number is on the left side (such as: i(5) * 5)
so i can do i(10) * 8 but not 8 * i(10) because the function parameters have to be in a certain order. I am aware i can just make a second overloaded function, but is tehre any way around it? im learning swift and it would be nice to learn some tips and tricks.
THanks,
from me

Comment: Why don't you use "swift-numerics" package provided in Apple Swift Packages? It has a ComplexModule which you can import.

Comment: @Asteroid presumably this is an example to illustrate the OP's question, and the OP is not asking about how to multiply a complex number by an Int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the parameters to Swift functions have a specific order. Swift does not support unordered parameters. As Craig points out in his answer, you can provide multiple versions of a function that take their parameters in different orders and have them all call the same function that actually implements the code.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, but you can write one function to call the other to avoid duplicating the implementation.

```
static func * (complex: i, number: Int) -> i{
    return i(number*complex.times)
}

static func * (number: Int, complex: i) -> i{
    return complex * number
}
```